# Attribute query search with case insensitive variable

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Trying to do a query with something like this:

```py
db.get_collection("collection").find({f"parent.{variable}": {"$exist": True}})
```

`parent` here would be an object and `variable` a string corresponding the the key that i am searching inside `parent`, I just want to get documents that have `variable` inside `parent` with a case insensitive search.

What would be the best way to make this query case insensitive ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do it.

```python
db.get_collection("collection").find({
  "$expr": {
    "$cond": [
      # is parent present and an object?
      {"$eq": [{"$type": "$parent"}, "object"]},
      # yes
      {
        "$in": [
          # lowercase your variable value
          variable.lower(), # or variable.casefold()
          { # make array of all lowercased field names
            "$map": {
              "input": {"$objectToArray": "$parent"},
              "in": {"$toLower": "$$this.k"}
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      # no
      False
    ]
  }
})
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qsUClkrwiuD).

Comment: You could also [use `"$reduce"` rather than `"$in"`/`"$map"`](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Yhj0OVpnHuq "link to monoplayground.net example -->").  I'm not sure which would be faster.

Comment: That's a really big query there lol, tried it on my side i didn't seem to match anything, I could return you some debugs if you want, but we ended up fixing the database by making all of what's inside parent lowercase so we can simplify the query (this is a much better option imo) but thanks for this gigantic query

Comment: @StephenMilic Glad you made progress.  Fixing the database is probably the better option.  I don't know why this didn't work for you - you can see that it works in mongoplayground.net.  It's moot now.  Best of luck!